# How to display a web service (SOAP) JSON result in a Drupal View

Tags: drupal, soap, service, view, web

I'm a Drupal beginner, and I would like to display a web service (SOAP) result (in JSON) in a page.
I would like to display the result in a table (so I think Drupal View would be nice to display it...), but I don't know how to bring the Web Service result to display it into a View.

I am using the module "wsclient" (http://drupal.org/project/wsclient) together with "Rules" to execute a web service method, and I am able to get its result into a message, but that's all I was able to do until now.

I'm new to Drupal. Can someone help me please, to perform this action in the best way?

I am using Drupal 7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature request in the wsclient issue queue for views integration: http://drupal.org/node/1215570

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments below, the following does not apply to the original question:

<strike>Have you considered using the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module instead?  There is already [views integration for it](http://drupal.org/project/services_views).</strike>

Comment: The Services module is for a Drupal site to *provide* an API for remote clients, not to consume a remote API.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the solution. I discovered that I could add PHP to a page with the "PHP filter" module (yes, I'm a very beginner in Drupal, I didn't know that =/), so I could add my own PHP code using "SoapClient", and it worked much easier for me now. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Thx jhedstrom. For 3 days I've been trying to get my rep up to 50 so I can comment on another thread... It's extremely hit and miss, and timing is everything. A lot of questions I can answer get answered while I'm still reading them. Frustrated, I've started answering questions before reading them fully.